# Optimize jQuery code

Tags: jquery

What would be a better to state the following:

```
 var active = '-active';
 if ($j('body').hasClass('faqs')) { $j('.faqs-support').toggleClass('faqs-support' + active); }
 if ($j('body').hasClass('cameras')) { $j('.camera-support').toggleClass('camera-support' + active); }
 if ($j('body').hasClass('manuals')) { $j('.manuals-support').toggleClass('manuals-support' + active); }
 if ($j('body').hasClass('downloads')) { $j('.downloads-support').toggleClass('downloads-support' + active); }
```

Comment: please mark it as code so it could be readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$j.each(['faqs', 'cameras', 'manuals', 'downloads'], function(i, e){
  if ($j('body').hasClass(e)) {
    $j('.'+e+'-support').toggleClass(e+'-support-active');
  }
});
```

Comment: You should cache `$j('body')` so it doesn't have to find elements by tag name a bunch of times, only to get the same result and throw things away.

Comment: @minitech: Yes, that is a possible further improvment, depending on whether you want simplicity or efficiency. Right now it just does it the same way as the original code.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $body = $j('body');
var arr = ['faqs', 'cameras', 'manuals', 'downloads'];
$j.each(arr, function(index, item) {
    if($body.hasClass(item)) $j('.' + item + '-support').toggleClass(item + '-support-active');
});
```

Is about how I would write that. Not much shorter or much more efficient, but clearer.

Comment: exactly what i was just about to write

Answer (score 2):

If that's the *only* class on the body, just grab the full className, and use it for the DOM selection and the `.toggleClass()`:

```
var body_class = document.body.className + '-support';
$j('.' + body_class).toggleClass(body_class + '-active');
```

Just one change you'd need to make would be to change `'.camera-support'` to `'.cameras-support'`. (Adding the "s".)

Answer (score 1):

if the body can only have one of those classes then you could do:

```
var cls = $j('body').attr('class');
if(cls)
    $j('.'+cls+'-support').toggleClass(cls+'-support-active');
```

Comment: +1 Looks like we were on the same track. :o) I'd just change `cls+'-support'+active` to `cls+'-support-active'`